# Help needed on writing a TCP socket using NSStream in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I current writing a TCP socket using NSStream. I'm able to open the stream but i can't write out anything (eg. a NSString or NSData).

Answer (score 2):

In your `-stream:handleEvent:` delegate method, when you receive an `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable` event for the `NSOutputStream`, you can send data using:

```
NSData *data = /* get some data… */;
const uint8_t *buffer = [data bytes];
NSUInteger length = [data length];
NSInteger nwritten = [outputStream write:buffer maxLength:length];
if (-1 == nwritten) {
    NSLog(@"Error writing to stream %@: %@", outputStream, [outputStream streamError]);
} else {
    NSLog(@"Wrote %ld bytes to stream %@.", (long)nwritten, outputStream);
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried the code but i have got the error "error writing to stream <__NSCFOutputStream: 0x102009f0>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=9 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Bad file descriptor"  do anyone know the problem?

Comment: It sounds like it's not backed by a file descriptor. Did you open the stream? Are you trying to write from the delegate callback as described?

Comment: Hi, i have used the following code to print out the streamStatus which returns a '2' so i guess the stream is open:  NSLog(@"Status of outputStream: %i", [outputStream streamStatus]);

Comment: HasBytesAvailable is for reading. For writing, you need to check the NSStream delegate events to see if it has HasSpaceAvailable

Comment: @xapod : can you help me for the same issue?